# ER Diagram in Barker Notation

Tags: database, database-design, diagrams, database-development

I engineered an ERD diagram using Barker's notation.
The problem was to make a database for system of water pipes where one node is connected to another using a section (pipe), each node can have unlimited number of pipes connected, but the pipe must have only two nodes that it's connected to.
Each node that is situated in certain location can have zero or more devices attached.
[image]

My other idea was to create one to many relation (section can be assigned to many nodes).
Is my diagram correct?

UPDATE:

After comments I changed the relations (embedded location in node as well).

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your model could be better.  As it is it allows a `section` to be related to many `node_sections` rather than to maximum of 2.  You could either:

- write a digit `2` on the diagram to show that there is a maximum cardinality at that end of the relationship; or
- drop `node_section` and have two 1:m relationships directly between `node` and `section`. If your pipe network has a fixed direction of flows then call the relationships `source` and `sink`, otherwise call them `end1` and `end2`.

Comment: This is an interesting answer.  However, does the [Barker notation](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/barkers-erd-notation) allow for an explicit cardinality to be used ?

Comment: It's a notation, not holy writ, make what use of it you wish, extend it where it is useful to do so, ignore features that are unimportant to you.

Comment: When using the second option, am I allowed to not explicitly set primary key for section? Either way it will get PF keys from both nodes that it's connected to.

Comment: You tell us: can a `section` exist independently of `nodes` ?  If so it needs a PK which is not just the FKs of the `nodes` it connects, if not, not so much.